# List<T> Any or Count?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

When I want to do something with a list I first check it if is not `null` or contains no elements (not to blow a `foreach`) and I usually use `list.Any()` but what is the best option - to use `list.Count > 0` , or to use `list.Any()`?

Comment: per style-guide: a list (collection, whatever) should never be null - rather it should be empty ...

Comment: Better to use Any() on Enumerables and Count on Collections. If someone feels writing '(somecollection.Count > 0)' will confuse or cause readability issues, better write it as an extension method name it Any(). Then everyone satisfied. Performance-wise as well as Readability-wise. So that all your code will have consistency and individual developer in your project need not worry about choosing Count vs Any.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

- Use `Count` if you're using a `List`, since it knows its size.
- Use `Length` for an `Array`
- If you just have an `IEnumerable` I would use `.Any()` over `.Count()` as it will be faster since it stops after checking one item.

Also check out this question: [Which method performs better: .Any() vs .Count() > 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0)

Comment: Don't! - If you can, __always__ use `Any` as it will translate to `Count` or `Length` wherever possible anyway and give a clear and uniform intention.

Comment: @TaW _always use Any as it will translate to Count or Length wherever possible anyway_ Can you back this up with some source code, because I don't believe you. Sorry.

Comment: I had reported the things I had found in various comments and posts but looking at the [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,6a1af7c3d17845e3) I have my doubts. I would still recommend Any() unless it would involve at trip to a database; but for other cases I doubt there would be any measurable performance hit (not sure how those casts factor in) and the clearer code remains a good reason.

Comment: @Silvermind Within the current dotnet runtime this will be used: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.5/src/libraries/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/AnyAll.cs#L11-L45 As for .NET framework there is no such check and thus `.Count` is prefered over `.Any()`. Interesting

Comment: Hey @Baklap4. I had the same argument here and if you read it you'll see I can make it break, but I have seen the source. ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824318/858757

Comment: Maybe have a look at the [benchmarks](https://www.tabsoverspaces.com/233649-comparing-speed-of-count-0-and-any).

Answer (score 4):

I use `list.Count > 0` just because it doesn't depend on the LINQ methods and so works on C# 2.0.

I personally avoid LINQ like the plague (because of its slow speed), and there's no reason to use extension methods here at all anyway.

**However**, a better solution would probably be to make your *own* version of `Any` that would take in a `null` reference, and return true if it's a collection with elements. That would save you the null check.

Comment: LINQ may be slower than something like a for-loop; but its not that slow that it should be avoided. I believe its worth the small performance hit since it makes the code more maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

`.Any()` is generally better to use than `.Count() > 0`. The reason for this is that if the items you are iterating over is not an `ICollection` then it will have to iterate the whole list to get the count.

But if the items is an `ICollection` (which a `List<T>` is) then it is just as fast or in some cases faster to use `Count()` (`Any()` iterates once regardless of underlying type in MS .Net but Mono tries to optimize this to `Count > 0` when the underlying items is an `ICollection`)

A great tool is [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1), the .Net source code and the [Mono source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs) which allows you to see how things are implemented.

Comment: btw ... .NET Reflector is non-free since version 7. an alternative: ILSpy (http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx)

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair : Why you said IEnumerable<T> is the evil interface / class ???

Comment: @Florian pfuh ... 1 year later ... no plan ... sry pal - i should rather delete the cmt :)

Comment: It doesn't appear that Mono optimizes the Any() to Count > 0 from this source code (it seems identical to the .net implementation): https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Entity Framework and have a huge table with many records Any() will be much faster.  I remember one time I wanted to check to see if a table was empty and it had millions of rows.  It took 20-30 seconds for Count() > 0 to complete.  It was instant with Any().

Answer (score 1):

**Any()** can be a performance enhancement because it may not have to iterate the collection to get the number of things. It just has to hit one of them. Or, for, say, LINQ-to-Entities, the generated SQL will be IF EXISTS(...) rather than SELECT COUNT ... or even SELECT * ....