# Check if list is empty in C#

Tags: c#, list, isnullorempty

I have a generic list object. I need to check if the list is empty.

How do I check if a `List<T>` is empty in C#?

Comment: So what's wrong with using `if (list.Count == 0) { /* ... */ }`?

Comment: Or `if (!list.Any())`

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8582344/492

Answer (score 214):

You can use [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0):

```
bool isEmpty = !list.Any();
if(isEmpty)
{
    // ...
}
```

If the list could be `null` you could use:

```
bool isNullOrEmpty = list?.Any() != true;
```

Comment: Would it not be best to check whether `list == null` first?

Comment: @ᴍᴀᴛᴛʙᴀᴋᴇʀ, var someList = new List<string>(); would be instantiated( and therefore not be null) but would be empty of elements to process

Answer (score 106):

If the list implementation you're using is `IEnumerable<T>` and Linq is an option, you can use `Any`:

```
if (!list.Any()) {

}
```

Otherwise you generally have a `Length` or `Count` property on arrays and collection types respectively.

Comment: As quick note: list.Any has much better performance than count.

Comment: @AdrianLopez: can you elaborate on that? If you have a `.Count` or `.Length` property as with `List` what could `.Any()` possibly do to be faster than checking the property of the collection which keeps track of the the current length or count? If you only have an Enumerator, then `.Any()` is of course faster than `.Count() > 0`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741617/listt-any-or-count?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @noox Looking at the (.Net Core) source, it seems `Any` checks to validate that retrieving the count is cheap before testing it, in cases where you have an `IListProvider<>` that doesn't track the count, it will enumerate once instead.

Answer (score 43):

```
    If (list.Count==0){
      //you can show your error messages here
    } else {
      //here comes your datagridview databind 
    }
```

You can make your datagrid visible false and make it visible on the else section.

Comment: @NetMage That's not how it works for list. It's an `O(1)` operation and there is no iterations done for counting elements. See [`List<T>.Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek You are correct, that comment was old as well as wrong :) Though in general, I would still prefer `Any()` as expressing intent better, as well as being more performant when you don't know you have an actual `List<T>`.

Answer (score 27):

What about using the `Count` property.

```
 if(listOfObjects.Count != 0)
 {
     ShowGrid();
     HideError();
 }
 else
 {
     HideGrid();
     ShowError();
 }
```

Comment: Count is a property not a method

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou Depends on whether it's  the Linq extension method exposed/being called, or native to the object.

Comment: @GrantThomas I took it as a List<T> object but yes you are correct.

Comment: what if listOfObjects is null?

Comment: @SabriMeviş a collection/ienumerable/list returned from a method should never be `null`. It should be an empty collection instead.

Answer (score 11):

You should use a simple `IF` statement

```
List<String> data = GetData();

if (data.Count == 0)
    throw new Exception("Data Empty!");

PopulateGrid();
ShowGrid();
```

Comment: Simplest and best way IMO.

Comment: If the method returns a null, the Count property will fail.
To keep the code concise, consider the null reference check operator "?". 
Example "if (data?.Count == 0) . . . . ." 
or the classic null check "if (data != null && someOtherCondition) ....."

Comment: Paste the following code into a dotnetfiddle and you'll see the 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
     
public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  List<string> stringList = null;
  if (stringList.Count == 0)
  {
   Console.WriteLine("no items in collection");
  }
 }
}
`

Comment: @daviesdoesit that would be beyond the scope of the question. This snippet clearly assumes `data` is defined.

Answer (score 8):

```
var dataSource = lst!=null && lst.Any() ? lst : null;
// bind dataSource to gird source
```

Answer (score 4):

gridview itself has a method that checks if the datasource you are binding it to is empty, it lets you display something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a gridview then use the empty data template: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx

```
      <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="true"
        runat="server">

        <emptydatarowstyle backcolor="LightBlue"
          forecolor="Red"/>

        <emptydatatemplate>

          <asp:image id="NoDataImage"
            imageurl="~/images/Image.jpg"
            alternatetext="No Image" 
            runat="server"/>

            No Data Found.  

        </emptydatatemplate> 

      </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: This is very ASP.NET specific.

Comment: I'm not a winforms guys but isn't a gridview asp.net specific. It's a datagridview in forms?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you need to force rerender parent component when you don't have a direct access to this parent component. Then you can use:

```
this.$parent.$forceUpdate();
```