# How to check if a StringBuilder is empty?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, stringbuilder

I want to test if the `StringBuilder` is empty but there is no `IsEmpty` method or property.

How does one determine this?

Comment: `sb.Length == 0` ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ow, so easy :/ Sorry, I am beginner in C#.

Comment: The fact that intellisense says "Gets or sets the length of the stringbuilder object', combined with the fact that the constructor takes a capacity as an argument and the fact that one can't SET the length of an existing string all combine to lead one to believe that Length probably reflects capacity.  The fact that it's the answer is highly unintuitive.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation of StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) it has only 4 properties. One of them is `Length`.

> The length of a StringBuilder object is defined by its number of Char objects.

You can use the [Length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.length(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

> Gets or sets the length of the current StringBuilder object.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (sb.Length != 0)
{
    // you have found some difference
}
```

Another possibility would be to treat it as a string by using the [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) method and condense the builder to a string using the `ToString` method. You can even grab the resulting string and assign it to a variable which you would use if you have found some differences:

```
string difference = ""; 

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(difference = sb.ToString()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(difference);      
}
```

Comment: It would have been easy to put `public bool Empty { get; } = this.Length == 0;`. Strange they did not have this idea.

Comment: @Boiethios that is true, I always wondered why they did not implement something like this.

Comment: And this is the same for the enumerables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867180/check-if-list-is-empty-in-c-sharp

Comment: I think it is because length property is writable. So you can limit the amount of characters the stringbuilder will parse to a string when calling toString method. So I don't even know when to truste kength property. The code posted here is quite good since it realys on the actualoutput of the stringbuilder

Comment: @RickerSilva that is a good point. Actually it´s even worse. If you set the `Length` property then `StringBuilder` will fill it up until that point with `0x00` characters. If you add then adterwards strings they will be appended to the zero hex string. If the `Length` property is set then unfortunately the `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sb.ToString())` or the `string.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.ToString())` approach also stops working

Answer (score 9):

use the `StringBuilder.Length` Property, here the [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.length(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (mySB.Length > 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Bang! is not empty!"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use *Length*. Here is how to use it:

```
      // create a StringBuilder object
    // with a String pass as parameter
    StringBuilder
        str
        = new StringBuilder("Hello World");

    // print string
    System.out.println("String = "
                       + str.toString());

    // get length of StringBuilder object and initialize if you use it more than ones
    int length = str.length();


   // you can check like
   if(len != 0)
    // print length
    System.out.println("length of String = "
                       + length);
```

Comment: This answer is not useful. It's just a shorter version of Mong Zhus answer.

Answer (score -3):

Use this, it will work:

```
StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
if(string.isnullorempty(Convert.toString(stringbuilder)))
```