# ArgumentOutOfRangeExeption for if statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is a snippet of the code that is causing the error

```c#
if(items[0] != null)
{
    equippedItem = items[0];
}
```

Here is a snippet of the items list:

```c#
public List<InventoryItem> items = new List<InventoryItem>();
```

Here is a snippet of the

```c#
public InventoryItem equippedItem;
```

EDIT: Can people explain why they are giving downvotes.

Comment: An ArgumentOutOfRangeException means that the index you supplied is beyond the number of items in the list. Are you sure `items` is populated with anything? If you have population logic, can you share it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if list is empty in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867180/check-if-list-is-empty-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Down votes in this question might be due to poor research on your part, its a simple problem that was asked and answered many times. But dont rely on down votes they come easily, some times a simple problem seems daunting until you know the solution, keep asking and learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this:

```
if(items[0] != null)
{
    equippedItem = items[0];
}
```

To this:

```
if(items.Any() && items[0] != null)
{
    equippedItem = items[0];
}
```

This will check if the list is initialized and has items. If it does have items, you can get the first item from the list.

And if you really want to get the first item from that list at all times, maybe use something like this:

```
InventoryItem equippedItem = items.FirstOrDefault();

if(equippedItem != null)
{
    // Add some cool code    
}
```

The FirstOrDefault gets the first item from a list. If there isn't a first item, the result will be the default value of the type (int = 0, bool = false, InventoryItem = null). You could also use First(), but that would throw an exception if there isn't a first (index 0).

I would try to avoid indexes as much as possible, because it's very sensitive for errors.

Comment: Why use `Any` though? Rather check the `Count != 0` instead of going through Linq

Comment: @derHugo A matter of taste? I like LINQ and I use it a lot. But if you rather use count or other methods, that is up to you. Besides, both count and Any throw exceptions when the list is NULL.

Comment: Was just wondering because if you know it is a list then the built-in property `Count` is way faster than using `Any` ;) we already know the list is not `null` but empty

Answer (score 0):

I actually found specifically that if you do this it works:

```
if (items.Count != 0)
        {
            if(items[0] != null)
            {
                equippedItem = items[0];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Index `0` must be allocated on the list for it to be used (`.Count > 0`), thats why you need the `.Any()` or `.Count > x` that way you check if the list has at least `x` size and you can use `item[x]`, if item is nullable you can then check if its null and use it as needed.

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://Https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-8.0)

> The exception that is thrown when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values