# Get count of unique characters between first and last letter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, console-application

I'm trying to get the unique characters count that are between the first and last letter of a word. For example: if I type Yellow the expected output is **Y3w**, if I type People the output should be **P4e** and if I type Money the output should be **M3y**. This is what I tried:

```
//var strArr = wordToConvert.Split(' ');
string[] strArr = new[] { "Money","Yellow", "People" };
List<string> newsentence = new List<string>();

foreach (string word in strArr)
{
    if (word.Length > 2)
    {
        //ignore 2-letter words
        string newword = null;

        int distinctCount = 0;
        int k = word.Length;
        int samecharcount = 0;
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < k - 2; i++)
        {
            if (word.ElementAt(i) != word.ElementAt(i + 1))
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                samecharcount++;
            }
        }
        distinctCount = count + samecharcount;

        char frst = word[0];
        char last = word[word.Length - 1];
        newword = String.Concat(frst, distinctCount.ToString(), last);
        newsentence.Add(newword);
    }
    else
    {
        newsentence.Add(word);
    }
}

var result = String.Join(" ", newsentence.ToArray());

Console.WriteLine("Output: " + result);
Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------");
```

With this code I'm getting the expect output for Yellow, but seems that is not working with People and Money. What can I do to fix this issue or also I'm wondering is maybe there is a better way to do this for example using LINQ/Regex.

Comment: Why would Yellow not yield Y4w?

Comment: @Maxqueue Because program should count only unique characters between First and Last character, in this case **ello*, contains double L so it count only once.

Comment: Linq you can simply do a 1 liner like `var result = word.First().ToString() + word.Substring(1, word.Length - 2).ToLower().Distinct().Count().ToString() + word.Last().ToString();`

Comment: you either increment count or samecharcount, to finally sum it into distinct count. However by the way you have it implemented you will allways get distinctCount to equeal k-2.  You probably want to only sum one of those I assume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation that uses Linq:

```
string[] strArr = new[]{"Money", "Yellow", "People"};
List<string> newsentence = new List<string>();
foreach (string word in strArr)
{
    if (word.Length > 2)
    {
        // we want the first letter, the last letter, and the distinct count of everything in between
        var first = word.First();
        var last = word.Last();
        var others = word.Skip(1).Take(word.Length - 2);

        // Case sensitive
        var distinct = others.Distinct();

        // Case insensitive
        // var distinct = others.Select(c => char.ToLowerInvariant(c)).Distinct();

        string newword = first + distinct.Count().ToString() + last;
        newsentence.Add(newword);
    }
    else
    {
        newsentence.Add(word);
    }
}

var result = String.Join(" ", newsentence.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

> M3y Y3w P4e

Note that this doesn't take account of case, so the output for `FiIsSh` is 4.

Comment: This works like a charm! Just for having all completed, how can I convert the var others to lowercase to avoid the output 4 for YeLlow

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the most performant, but here is another example using linq:

```
var words = new[] { "Money","Yellow", "People" };
var transformedWords = words.Select(Transform);
var sentence = String.Join(' ', transformedWords);

public string Transform(string input)
{
    if (input.Length < 3)
    {
        return input;
    }
    var count = input.Skip(1).SkipLast(1).Distinct().Count();
    return $"{input[0]}{count}{input[^1]}";
}
```

Comment: I forgot about `SkipLast` :)

Comment: @stuartd Yeah, I don't use it that much. I think it is one of the latest additions.

Comment: You're right, it's new in .Net Core. I used it the other day for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it with the help of *Linq*. e.g. (**C# 8+**)

```
private static string EncodeWord(string value) => value.Length <= 2
  ? value
  : $"{value[0]}{value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2).Distinct().Count()}{value[^1]}";
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "Money","Yellow", "People"
  };

  var report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test} :: {EncodeWord(test)}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
Money :: M3y
Yellow :: Y3w
People :: P4e
```

Comment: Nice use of the range operator, `^1`. Worth mentioning it requires C#8 though.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people have put up some good solutions.  I have two solutions for you: one uses LINQ and the other does not.

**LINQ, Probably not much different from others**

```
if (str.Length < 3) return str;

var midStr = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2);
var midCount = midStr.Distinct().Count();
return string.Concat(str[0], midCount, str[str.Length - 1]);
```

**Non-LINQ**

```
if (str.Length < 3) return str;
    
var uniqueLetters = new Dictionary<char, int>();
var midStr = str.Substring(1, str.Length - 2);
foreach (var c in midStr)
{
   if (!uniqueLetters.ContainsKey(c))
   {
      uniqueLetters.Add(c, 0);
   }
}
        
var midCount = uniqueLetters.Keys.Count();
return string.Concat(str[0], midCount, str[str.Length - 1]);
```

I tested this with the following 6 strings:

> Yellow
> Money
> Purple
> Me
> You
> Hiiiiiiiii

Output:

```
LINQ: Y3w, Non-LINQ: Y3w  
LINQ: M3y, Non-LINQ: M3y  
LINQ: P4e, Non-LINQ: P4e  
LINQ: Me, Non-LINQ: Me  
LINQ: Y1u, Non-LINQ: Y1u  
LINQ: H1i, Non-LINQ: H1i
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lMNFmX)

Performance-wise I'd guess they're pretty much the same, if not identical, but I haven't run any real perf test on the two approaches.  I can't imagine they'd be much different, if at all.  The only real difference is that the second route expands `Distinct()` into what it probably does under the covers anyway (I haven't looked at the source to see if that's true, but that's a pretty common way to get a count of .  And the first route is certainly less code.

Comment: You could als use a hashet. Even with a counter variable incrmenting when `if (hashset.Add(c))`. Also, you should use `Count` instead of `Count()`. ;)

Comment: @Silvermind So I looked up both of those, just to be sure. According to [this](https://theburningmonk.com/2011/03/hashset-vs-list-vs-dictionary/) the difference between `hashset.Add()` and `dictionary.Add()` is pretty minimal. (Though that article is 10 years old now so take that for what it's worth.)  As for `Count` vs. `Count()`, under the covers the latter calls the former if that property exists; otherwise it enumerates through the list.  So it shouldn't make any difference. :)  (Though the property is probably preferable just to avoid unintended casting-related performance issues!)

Comment: about the dictionary; I know it is pretty minimal, but that is not why I suggested it. Since you don't need the value, why should you create the ambiguity that a dictionary seems necessary. If it is not necessary and it does not add value, it creates that ambiguity.

Comment: About the count; First of all, Enumerable does not know anything about ICollection and it shouldn't. ICollection is built on top of IEnumerable, so I higly doubt that the programmers would lock themselfs into that (circular) dependency. Secondly, It has been said before, but none have brought any prove that it checks for a Count property, which is why I brought up IColection. I would be amazed if you find actual dotnet source code that does that. ;)

Comment: Also, I could implement my own collection and let the count property throw an error. Why would Enumerable.Count() break my code?

Comment: @Silvermind Fair point about the dictionary.  A hashset would get the job done with a smaller memory footprint. :)  As for `ICollection/IEnumerable`, [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Count.cs,41ef9e39e54d0d0b) is the source for the LINQ `Count()` extension.  It checks to see if `source` is an `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection` and if it is it calls `source.Count`.  Otherwise it starts enumerating through the items.

Comment: So, now I am amazed, thanks, ;). I'm going to dive into that. Do you agree with my point about throwing an exception when the count property is accessed. It may seem silly, but when I pass my hidden collection to a public method that accepts IEnumerable, I would not expect it to break. Btw, I'm on my mobile and I'm having trouble finding out if this is the source of dotnet core or framework. They might do the same, but I'm actually stunned.

Comment: Any time!  And I'm about 90% sure that's .NET Core, though I think it's unlikely that the code for that particular method differs between the two.  It's pretty generic code. :)  I'm also having trouble verifying that, though.  As for the exception, you *could* do that.  I can't think of a scenario where you'd want to offhand, but I suppose there's nothing stopping you.  I think in the end you're right: `Count()` is nice, but it's what I alluded to earlier - using `Count` means you know exactly what the collection is, and that's probably ultimately safer.

Answer (score 0):

I Would use Linq for that purpose:

```
            string[] words = new string[] { "Yellow" , "People", "Money", "Sh" }; // Sh for 2 letter words (or u can insert 0 and then remove the trinary operator)
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                int uniqeCharsInBetween = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 2).ToCharArray().Distinct().Count();
                string result = word[0] + (uniqeCharsInBetween == 0 ? string.Empty : uniqeCharsInBetween.ToString()) + word[word.Length - 1];
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
```