# How to optimize Linq query with large number of records?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization, ef-core-3.1

Please help me to optimize the below code. I have tried different methods but I am not getting a significant performance improvement. There are around 30k entries in database and it's taking around 1 min to load in local.

```cs
var alarms = from healthIssue in _context.HealthIssues.AsNoTracking()
                         join asset in _context.Assets.AsNoTracking() on healthIssue.AssetNumber equals asset.SerialNumber into joinedTable
                         from data in joinedTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new
                         {
                             ID = healthIssue.ID,
                             AssetNumber = healthIssue.AssetNumber,                                                         
                             AlarmName = healthIssue.AlarmName, 
                             Crew = data.Crew,                           
                         };
//alarmsViewModelList count is 30k  
var alarmsViewModelList = await alarms.ToListAsync();
//groupedData count = 12k 
var groupedData = alarmsViewModelList.Select(c => new { c.AssetNumber,c.AlarmName}).Distinct().ToList();
// filteralarms' count = 20k 
var filteralarms = (alarmsViewModelList.Where(c => c.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown).ToList());
for (int j = 0; j < groupedData.Count; j++)
{
    var alarm = groupedData[j];
    //The line is actually slowing the code.
    var alarmlist = filteralarms.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.AlarmName == alarm.AlarmName && c.AssetNumber == alarm.AssetNumber
                            ).Select
                            (c => new
                            {
                                HealthIssueID = c.ID,
                                AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime),
                                AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel,
                                
                            }).OrderByDescending(c =>c.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime).ToList();
    int alarmCount = alarmlist.Count;
    if (alarmCount > 1)
    {
        businessLogicFunction(alarmlist); 
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear where in your code the performance is bad. there are 3 statements preceding the loop and then the loop itself. Also, what is `alarms` to begin with? And why ToList everywhere?

Comment: @GertArnold I have updated the alarms details in questions. I removed the ToList() and used foreach loop. But it only slowed down the code. I am not sure why that happened. Do you any suggestion on how to optimize this?

Comment: Also good to mention which ORM this is. Entity Framework? And which version?

Comment: @GertArnold It's Entityframework Core 3.1.6.

Comment: Is it possible to get Model Classes and/or some DB schema? EF core performance is somehow tied to the DB schema, too AFAIK.

Comment: How long database query (thing before var groupedData) takes?

Comment: @Evk That happens pretty fast actually. There is no delay in that. The loop takes a lot of time to execute.

Comment: And what about `businessLogicFunction`, also very fast?

Comment: @Evk Ya, it's also not that slow.

Comment: Can you write a stored procedure in your database to get the maximum speed? You want your DB engine to do all the filtering, grouping, etc., and to give you exact data you can propagate to your UI/API in C#.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this in a fiddle using synthetic data generated with `Enumerable.Range()` here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GjGJSk.  However, it doesn't compile.  1) The anonymous type objects in `alarmsViewModelList` don't have a property `AlarmSeverityLevel`.  2) `int alarmCount = alarmlist.Count;` -- `alarmList` doesn't have a `Count` property.  You could use the extension method `.Count()`, maybe that's what you want"  Anyway, I realize this comment is late, but is there any chance you could [edit] your question to share a compilable [mcve]?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get to a [mcve] myself, and I've found that the code is clearly not real code. You're claiming that it works and is slow, but the code you've posted just has syntax errors. It's not real code. Please fix it.

Comment: In face, the `HealthIssue` class also needs `AlarmLastUpdatedTime` and you have `businessLogicFunction` taking a list of anonymous variables. It's really a black hole of processing to do that. You need to post real code and do timings of each distinct chuck of code to see where you're having issues. If it's in `businessLogicFunction` then the whole question is a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 4):

You basically group data by AlarmName + AssetNumber, filter our alarms with severity level `Unknown` then run business function on grouped batches (after minor adjustment). More efficient approach to this would be something like this:

```
var grouped = alarmsViewModelList
    // throw away unknown, you are not using them anywhere
    .Where(c => c.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown)
    // group by AssetNumber + AlarmName
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.AssetNumber, c.AlarmName })
    .Select(gr => new
    {
        gr.Key.AlarmName,
        gr.Key.AssetNumber,
        // convert batch of this group to the desired form
        Items = gr.Select(c => new
        {
            HealthIssueID = c.ID,
            AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime),
            AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel,
        }).OrderByDescending(c => c.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime).ToList()
    });

foreach (var data in grouped) {
    if (data.Items.Count > 1) {
        businessLogicFunction(data.Items);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I can make with linq.

```
  //alarmsViewModelList count is 30k  
var alarmsViewModelList = await alarms.ToListAsync();
//groupedData is almost 12k 
var groupedData = alarmsViewModelList.Select(c => new { c.AssetNumber,c.AlarmName}).Distinct().ToList();
// filteralarms' count is almost 20k 
var filteralarms = alarmsViewModelList.Where(c => c.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown).OrderByDescending(c => DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime));
for (int j = 0; j < groupedData.Count; j++)
{
    var alarm = groupedData[j];
    //The line is actually slowing the code.
    var alarmlist = filteralarms.Where(c => c.AlarmName == alarm.AlarmName && c.AssetNumber == alarm.AssetNumber);
    
    if (alarmlist.Count() > 1)
    {
        businessLogicFunction(alarmlist.Select
                            (c => new
                            {
                                HealthIssueID = c.ID,
                                AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime),
                                AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel,
                                
                            }).ToList()); 
    }
filteralarms = filteralarms.Where(c => c.AlarmName != alarm.AlarmName || c.AssetNumber != alarm.AssetNumber).ToList();

}
```

Above code O(2n) I think.
And if you can, you can make it faster by removing ToList() in businessLogicFunction like.

```
businessLogicFunction(alarmlist.Select
                        (c => new
                        {
                            HealthIssueID = c.ID,
                            AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime),
                            AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel,

                        }));
```

Changed it so don't use skip insted index that way way faster
Even faster approach is order the lists and skip the rest like this:

```
//alarmsViewModelList count is 30k  
        var alarmsViewModelList = alarms.ToList();
        // here the groupedData list look like this {(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1),(6,1)}. because the list is orderd by assetNumber then by alarmName
        var groupedData = alarmsViewModelList.Select(c => new { c.AssetNumber, c.AlarmName }).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.AssetNumber ).ThenBy(c => c.AlarmName).ToList();
        // here the filteralarms list look like this {(1,1), (1,1) (1,1), (2,1),(2,1),(3,1),(3,1),(3,1),(4,1)...}
        var filteralarms = alarmsViewModelList.Where(c => c.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown).OrderBy(c => c.AssetNumber).ThenBy(c => c.AlarmName).AsEnumerable();
        int k  = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < groupedData.Count; j++)
        {
            
            var alarm = groupedData[j];
            //The line is actually slowing the code.
            var alarmlist = new List<Alarm>();
            for(; k<filteralarms.Count();k++)
            {
                if (filteralarms[k].AlarmName == alarm.AlarmName && filteralarms[k].AssetNumber == alarm.AssetNumber)
                {
                    alarmlist.Add(filteralarms[k]);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (alarmlist.Count() > 1)
            {
                businessLogicFunction(alarmlist.Select
                                    (c => new
                                    {
                                        HealthIssueID = c.ID,
                                        AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime,
                                        AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel,

                                    }).OrderByDescending(c => c.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime).ToList());
            }
```

Above code is O(n) I think.

Comment: I tried this and it's somehow making it slower than before :(

Comment: Added a line: filteralarms = filteralarms.Where(c => c.AlarmName != alarm.AlarmName || c.AssetNumber != alarm.AssetNumber).ToList(); this removes the already checked items.

Comment: @StarLord i change my answer

Comment: Adding a break at the end will exit the loop and won't be all the matching alarms right? It'll give wrong result I think.

Comment: The list is orderd so all the same name and number be side each other so when the if statement is false we can assume the list has no more of that item. So break the loop. Then we skip the length of the find list count. Hope it make sense

Comment: {5,6,5,6,1,9,9} then order it like {1,5,5,6,6,9,9}  in the second list we can see all the same are next to each other so when the next is not not like before the loop can skip

Comment: In my testing i got 15-13 second run time

Comment: var groupedData = alarmsViewModelList.Select(c => new { c.AssetNumber, c.AlarmName }).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c.AssetNumber ).ThenBy(c => c.AlarmName).ToList();
        var filteralarms = alarmsViewModelList.Where(c => c.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown).OrderBy(c => c.AssetNumber).ThenBy(c => c.AlarmName).AsEnumerable(); this two line need it order to work

Comment: now even faster 2-0.5 second run time @StarLord

Comment: I tried this implementation but sadly I am not seeing a better performance. It's more or less the same speed as before.

Comment: @LévayLőrinc - The `businessLogicFunction` method is a blackhole for performance. There's little we can do to improve performance without finding out what's going on in there.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating two lists derived from `alarmsViewModelList`:

1. `groupedData` which are the distinct values of `{ alarm.AssetNumber, alarm.AlarmName }`
2. `filteralarms` which are all alarms with `AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown`.

After creating these two lists, you loop through the first **and attempt to cross-reference it with the values in the second via a linear search**.  This is an n-squared operation.  But since the two lists were originally created from the same source data `alarmsViewModelList`, you can maintain a list of original objects for each grouping key by using [`Enumerable.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0) instead of [`Distinct()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-7.0).  Doing so should completely eliminate the need for the n-squared cross-reference.

In addition, since you only want to pass alarms with a known severity level to your business logic function, you can filter for them upfront, before doing the grouping.  This should improve performance linearly, depending on the number of alarms that are skipped.

Thus your code should look something like:

```
var groupedData = alarmsViewModelList
    .Where(c => c.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown)
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.AssetNumber, c.AlarmName })
    .Select(g => g.Select(c =>
                          new {
                              HealthIssueID = c.ID,
                              AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime),
                              AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel,
                          }).OrderByDescending(c =>c.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime).ToList())
    .Where(l => l.Count > 0);

foreach (var alarmList in groupedData)
    businessLogicFunction(alarmList);
```

Notes:

- When you do [`ToListAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tolistasync?view=efcore-7.0) you are fetching all the data locally,  You might want to try doing the filtering or grouping on the server side rather than the client side.

Demo fiddles using synthetic data generated using `Enumerable.Range()` here:

1. The original code with elapsed time = 4.2335498 seconds [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o7zuox).

   I had to tweak the code somewhat just to make it compile.
2. The modified code with with elapsed time = 0.0393871 seconds [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FKpYEe).

Answer (score 0):

Try it with AsNoTracking, if there is an OrderBy,OrderByDescending record, use it at the end

```
var iq_filteralarms = alarmsViewModelList.Where(c => c.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown).AsNoTracking(); /* IQueryable */
            foreach (var item in alarmsViewModelList.Select(c => new
            {
                c.AssetNumber,
                c.AlarmName
            }).Distinct())
            {
                var iq_alarmlist = iq_filteralarms.Where(c => c.AlarmName == item.AlarmName && c.AssetNumber == item.AssetNumber).Select(c=> new { 
c.ID, 
c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime,
c.AlarmSeverityLevel
});
                if (iq_alarmlist.Count() > 1)
                {
                    businessLogicFunction(iq_alarmlist.AsEnumerable().Select(c => new
                    {
                        HealthIssueID = c.ID,
                        AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime),
                        AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel,

                    }).OrderByDescending(c => c.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple logical performance gain would be to remove resolved alarms as you go:

```
...
var alarm = groupedData[j];
//The line is actually slowing the code.
var matchingAlarms = filteralarms.Where(c => c.AlarmName == alarm.AlarmName && c.AssetNumber == alarm.AssetNumber);
var alarmlist = filteralarms.Except(matchingAlarms
                        ).Select
                         (c => new
                         {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Connor. I have tried this method, but it's making the performance worse.

Answer (score 0):

If you populate a dictionary with the keys being the predicate values concatenated and the value being the selected alarm properties you should be able to do much better.

```
var alarms = from healthIssue in _context.HealthIssues.AsNoTracking()
                     join asset in _context.Assets.AsNoTracking() on healthIssue.AssetNumber equals asset.SerialNumber into joinedTable
                     from data in joinedTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new
                     {
                         ID = healthIssue.ID,
                         AssetNumber = healthIssue.AssetNumber,                                                         
                         AlarmName = healthIssue.AlarmName, 
                         Crew = data.Crew,                           
                     };

//alarmsViewModelList count is 30k  
var alarmsViewModelList = await alarms.ToListAsync();
//groupedData count = 12k 
var groupedData = alarmsViewModelList
  .Select(c => new { c.AssetNumber,c.AlarmName})
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();
// filteralarms' count = 20k 
var filteralarms = alarmsViewModelList
 .Where(c => c.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown).ToList();

//populate an in memory dictionary with a key that is the where clause predicate
var alarmDict = new Dictioanry<string, Alarm>();
foreach (var c in filterAlarms) {
  var key = c.AlarmName+"|"+c.AssetNumber;
    if (!alarmDict.TryGetValue(key, out var list)) {
      alarmDict[key] = new List<Alarm>();
    }
    var alarm = new { 
      HealthIssueID = c.ID,
      AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime), 
      AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel};
      
  alarmDict[key].Add(alarm);
}

for (int j = 0; j < groupedData.Count; j++)
{
  var alarm = groupedData[j];
  //use dictionary for faster results. building the dictionary is now the more expensive operation
  var key = alarm.AlarmName+"|"+alarm.AssetNumber;
  if (alarmDict.TryGetValue(key, out var alarms)) {
    var alarmlist = alarms
      .OrderByDescending(c => c.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime)
      .ToList();
      
    int alarmCount = alarmlist.Count;
    if (alarmCount > 1)
    {
       businessLogicFunction(alarmlist); 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with these three optimizations in your code.

```
var groupedData = alarmsViewModelList.GroupBy(c => new { c.AssetNumber,c.AlarmName }).ToListAsync();

var filteralarms = await alarmsViewModelList.Where(c => c.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown).ToListAsync();


foreach (var alarm in groupedData)
    var alarmlist = filteralarms.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.AlarmName == alarm.Key.AlarmName && c.AssetNumber == alarm.Key.AssetNumber)
                    .Select(c => new
                    {
                        HealthIssueID = c.ID,
                        AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime),
                        AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel,
                        
                    }).OrderByDescending(c => c.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any answers for optimising of getting `alarmsViewModelList` query because you already fetch 30K records from database and then in the application memory trying to filter alarms but why not filter them on the database side.

It is worth to mention the `AsNoTracking()` is useless here because you use anonymous type for result and EF will track only entities.

I think OP didn't clear these ones:

- `AlarmSeverityLevel` and `AlarmLastUpdateDateTime`  come from which tables? (but I assume it's from first table)
- you select the `Crew` but not used later, why? we can remove it so?

So the statement could be like this:

```cs
var alarms = Context.HealthIssues
            .Where(x => x.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown)
            .Select(x => new { HealthIssueID= x.Id, x.AssetNumber , x.AlarmName ,x.AlarmSeverityLevel ,x.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime })
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.AssetNumber, x.AlarmName })
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ItemsCount = x.Count(),
                Items = x.Select(s => new
                {
                    AlarmSeverityLevel = s.AlarmSeverityLevel,
                    AlarmLastUpdatedTime = s.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime,//for not generating translate error, can change later,
                    HealthIssueID = s.HealthIssueID
                }).OrderByDescending(o => o.AlarmLastUpdatedTime)
            }).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < alarms.Count; i++)
        {
            var alarm = alarms[i];
            //you can update AlarmLastUpdatedTime here for alarm.Items

            if(alarm.ItemsCount > 1)
                businessLogicFunction(alarm. Items);

        }
```

I can't run this query please let me know if there is any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `ToList()` and `AsEnumerable()` unnecessarily, as these operations can be expensive.try to use the `IQueryable` interface to filter and sort the data, so that the database can handle these operations for you eg:

```cs
var alarms = from healthIssue in _context.HealthIssues.AsNoTracking()
             join asset in _context.Assets.AsNoTracking() on healthIssue.AssetNumber equals asset.SerialNumber into joinedTable
             from data in joinedTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 ID = healthIssue.ID,
                 AssetNumber = healthIssue.AssetNumber,
                 AlarmName = healthIssue.AlarmName,
                 Crew = data.Crew,
             };
```

Instead of using a `for loop` to iterate over `groupedData`, you can use `foreach` is generally more efficient because it avoids the overhead

if possible, try to move the `businessLogicFunction` call outside of the loop, so that it is only called once for each distinct `alarm.AlarmName`
and `alarm.AssetNumber` combination.

```cs
// filteralarms count = 20k 
var filteralarms = alarms.Where(c => c.AlarmSeverityLevel != AlarmSeverityLevel.Unknown);

// groupedData count = 12k 
var groupedData = filteralarms.Select(c => new { c.AssetNumber, c.AlarmName }).Distinct();

foreach (var alarm in groupedData)
{
    // alarmlist count = ?
    var alarmlist = filteralarms.Where(c => c.AlarmName == alarm.AlarmName && c.AssetNumber == alarm.AssetNumber
                                ).Select
                                (c => new
                                {
                                    HealthIssueID = c.ID,
                                    AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime),
                                    AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel,

                                }).OrderByDescending(c => c.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime);

    if (alarmlist.Any()
    {
        businessLogicFunction(alarmlist);
    }
}
```

[Any over Count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741805/10909874)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the issue is that you're looping over a Where clause and ToList 12k times - that's slowing you down. What if you change out this block:

```
for (int j = 0; j < groupedData.Count; j++)
{
    var alarm = groupedData[j];
    //The line is actually slowing the code.
    var alarmlist = filteralarms.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.AlarmName == alarm.AlarmName && c.AssetNumber == alarm.AssetNumber
                            ).Select
                            (c => new
                            {
                                HealthIssueID = c.ID,
                                AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(c.AlarmLastUpdatedTime),
                                AlarmSeverityLevel = c.AlarmSeverityLevel,
                                
                            }).OrderByDescending(c =>c.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime).ToList();
    int alarmCount = alarmlist.Count;
    if (alarmCount > 1)
    {
        businessLogicFunction(alarmlist); 
    }

}
```

to a join? This will significantly improve your performance. Since you're ok with using query syntax, try using a more natural-looking join like this:

```
var alarmlist = from g in groupedData
                join f in filteralarms on g.AssetNumber equals f.AssetNumber
                where g.AlarmName == f.AlarmName
                select new
                {
                    HealthIssueID = f.ID,
                    AlarmLastUpdateDateTime = DateTimeHelpers.FromEpochSecondsUTC(f.AlarmLastUpdatedTime),
                    AlarmSeverityLevel = f.AlarmSeverityLevel,
                };

int alarmCount = alarmlist.Count();
if (alarmCount > 1)
{
    businessLogicFunction(alarmlist.OrderByDescending(o => o.AlarmLastUpdateDateTime).ToList());
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am going say that your question is the wrong question. It is good to write efficient business logic for processing your data, and often an efficient algorithm can improve performance by orders of magnitude.(Sorting lists is a great example here)

However, if you want to make this go faster, you might look at optimizing your data as you pull it from the db. Modern databases are highly tuned to filter and join data very fast, by people who are thinking about nothing but this. Provided that you have some decent indexing on your tables / blobs /graph /whatever, you could include some clauses in your db query to filter out records that don't need to be processed.

Pulling 30k records and sending it over the wire is going to take (in db time scales) a lot of effort. I would hope that you can grab all this in a single query, as retrieving it in multiple pulls will take even longer.

I have no data on how log your query is running for, or what the load time is to transfer and de-serialize your data. I will be willing to bet you money though, that if you filter dead records in your query and say cut your payload in half that you will gain a huge performance boost. *Don't load records that you don't need to process.* Also, if you can properly filter on the metal, your linq will probably just turn into a list that can be processed in o(n) time. Why tune your Linq, if you can tune the data it runs on?

Good luck.