# Does this Linq query produce multiple run trips to the SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Here is the code:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeItem> DescendantsAndSelf()
{
    yield return this;
    foreach (var item in Children.SelectMany(x => x.DescendantsAndSelf())
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

I got this code from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814278/184773

This is a recursive linq query. i want to implement this but afraid it my bring my server down. Do you know if this performans multiple run trips to the server?

Comment: There's no indication of SQL server in here *at all*. Where does the SQL part come in? This looks more likely to be XML... please give more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Not xml, he linked to your own code... don't you recognize it? :)

Comment: @gilly3: I didn't at the time, no :) But I still can't see where SQL Server comes in. The answer at the moment can only be "maybe".

Comment: The simplest way to know would be to **check**. Turn on your SQL Server Profiler and see how many queries are being made.

Comment: I assumed the original question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4814278/184773) was referring to sql server. Now that i look at it - it does not refer to sql server at all. i will delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make just one call you could implement a recursive query in SQL using a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and expose it to your application as a stored procedure which can be called from LINQ.