# How can I get a list of CollectionBase items?

Tags: c#, linq, collectionbase

In C#, if I have a CollectionBase of type T, and each item in the CollectionBase can have a child CollectionBase of the same type T, how can I get a list of all type T objects without using a recursive function?

Does LINQ have a feature to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can the child items have children, etc? Why don't you want to use recursion?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814242/linq-recursion-function).

Comment: Can you show us some code for the CollectionBase? I asume SelectMany is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Wes Dyer wrote actually a nice topic on this, have a [look](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx).

As for your case I think you would need an iterator, probably something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Func<T,IEnumerable<T>> f) 
{
   return e.SelectMany(c => f(c).Flatten(f)).Concat(e);
}
```

This is answer is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11830287/4323885).

**EDIT:** I just remember that you can also [traverse](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/226162) the tree.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Traverse<T>(T item, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childSelector)
{
    var stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(item);
    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;
        foreach (var child in childSelector(next))
        stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```